# How to map a string to a font awesome icon

Tags: reactjs, typescript, font-awesome

Hey folks I've been working through some mapping issues with font awesome and I am pretty close. I am mapping over a group of icons and returning an object that maps the string to  a font awesome icon. I just don't know how to convert that string into the actual icon.

**For example**

```
import { faSave } from '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

  icons.map((item) => {
    tmpArray.push(
      {
        [item.iconName] : faSave // this works but I need a unique icon for each string
        [item.iconName] : 'fa'+upperFirst(camelCase(item.iconName)) // creates faSave string but needs to be an icon
      }
    )
  })
```

Comment: The actual icon as in the SVG, image, font, code, or HTML?

Comment: @code it's a svg from font awesome import { faSave } from '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a map of the names to the icons. This can be as simple as an object:

```
const iconsMap = { faSave } // using shorthand property initializer

// ...

icons.map((item) => {
  tmpArray.push(
    {
      [item.iconName] : iconsMap['fa'+upperFirst(camelCase(item.iconName)) as keyof typeof iconsMap]
    }
  )
})
```

You'll then be able to get the correct icon for the name by indexing into it.